# How to model this data on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
    "Number" : 400,
    "Page" : 24,
    "DC" : "NE",
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
    "Number" : 300,
    "Page" : 14,
    "DC" : "100",
}
```

And i want to model this data so it stays like this:

```
{Crs:{[
   {Cr: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
        "Number" : 400,
        "Page" : 24,
        "DC" : "NE",
    }},
   {Cr: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
        "Number" : 300,
        "Page" : 14,
        "DC" : "100",
    }},
]}}
```

I read something about Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents but i really dont know how it works.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/

Comment: Can you provide some more information?  Are you wanting to append objects to this array?  Are you wanting to update specific objects within the array?  Thanks.

Comment: @R.A.Lucas  I want to make an update to the information that i imported to mongo.

Comment: That isn't helpful information. You're saying you want to "update information". That's an incredibly vague statement. The question is how--in what way, shape, or form--do you want to make this update? Is your intention to update an existing array element? Or is your intention to append a new array element? If you want to append a new array element, you'll want to use the `$push` operator on your array field. Please review the MongoDB documentation, provide your current update query, and be more specific in your question. We can recommend changes after you've done so.

Comment: @B.Fleming  I want to model this date so that it is structured as explained in the question.Something relatade with One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents but i dont know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use aggregation

```
> db.crs.aggregate(
    [
        {$group : {_id : null, crs : {$push : {cr : "$$ROOT"}}}},
        {$project : {_id : 0}}
    ]
).pretty()
```

you can also write the result data to another collection using `$out`

add below as last stage in aggregate pipeline

```
{$out : "crs"} // create collection crs
```

output

```
> db.crs.aggregate([{$group : {_id : null, crs : {$push : {cr : "$$ROOT"}}}}, {$project : {_id : 0}}]).pretty()
{
    "crs" : [
        {
            "cr" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d480"),
                "Number" : 400,
                "Page" : 24,
                "DC" : "NE"
            }
        },
        {
            "cr" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5a75baada0f20bd4e612d489"),
                "Number" : 300,
                "Page" : 14,
                "DC" : "100"
            }
        }
    ]
}
>
```

Comment: Can you explain me how group works and why you use _id:null and cr : "$$ROOT"?

Comment: `$group` is to group documents by specific keys, keys mentioned in _id, but here we don't need to group documents by any key so `_id : null` is used, and `$$ROOT` is a special variable which holds the current processing document, simply pushing all documents to array

Comment: Another thing Can i use multiple $group or $push functions? Because i need to make a lot of changes in the document.

Comment: yes, you can add multiple stages, please check documentation

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation here should be of some help: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array

And in your case it would be something similar to this:

```
db.nameOfCollection.updateOne(
  { _id: ObjectId('idhere'), "Crs.Cr.Number": 400 },
  { $set: { "Crs.$.Cr.DC" : "SomethingNew" } }
)
```

One thing here, I'm not sure you're data structure seems correct as you have an array inside an object...why not just an array, i.e.

```
Crs: [{...}, {...}]
```